# telephone no only allow number to type in checkout page : mangoe 2

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

[image: 1]

by default, Magento allows adding character

User can only add numbar or integer in telephon field

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the validation rules for the telephone field in the code if necessary to meet your specific requirements.